# Can I get the jQuery UI datepicker elements to not reset when a date is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

By default, the jQuery UI datepicker resets the calendar HTML whenever a date is picked. I want to be able to change/add elements of the calendar (add images, backgrounds, etc) and have them stay after a date is clicked.

For example, this script starts as an inline date picker with the background of the 24th blue. When you click another date (say the 15th), the HTML resets and the blue background disappears. I want it to STAY blue after a date is clicked.

```
<script>

$(function(){
    $('#cal').datepicker({
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            console.log(dateText);
            // dont do anything else
        }
    });
    $('.ui-state-default:contains(24)').css('background-color','blue');
});

</script>   

<div id='cal'></div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DtvZM/

See how when you click a day, the 24th turns from blue to white.. I want it to STAY blue.

Note: This is just an example to demonstrate the problem, and not my actual code.

I'm looking to see if there is an easy solution to this before modifying the jQuery UI widget code.

Comment: What's your goal, to allow multiple date choices to stick on the calendar between it being opened and closed?

Comment: My goal is to add/modify HTML of the calendar and have my changes stay after a date is clicked. Things like changing background colors, adding images, changing borders, etc

Comment: Also, there is no opening/closing. The calendar is inline (see demo/code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved that this isn't possible without modifying the UI datepicker code, which is what I ended up doing -

In the _selectDate method, I changed the line:

```
if (inst.inline)
    this._updateDatepicker(inst);
```

to

```
if (inst.inline) {
    inst.stay = true;
    this._updateDatepicker(inst);
    inst.stay = false;
}
```

Then in _updateDatepicker method, I changed

```
inst.dpDiv.empty().append(this._generateHTML(inst));
```

to

```
if (!inst.stay) {
    inst.dpDiv.empty().append(this._generateHTML(inst));
}
```

Now UI will not reset the calendar HTML when a date is selected.

Answer (score -1):

Can you not move the `$('.ui-state-default:contains(24)').css('background-color','blue');` *inside* the `onSelect` callback? You'll still need to do that to ensure newly selected 24's also get blue I believe.

Also, I think I'd add classes instead and keep the actual styling in CSS.

```
$(function(){
    $('#cal').datepicker({
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            console.log(dateText);
            $('.ui-state-default:contains(24)').css('background-color','blue');
            // dont do anything else
        }
    });
});
```

Edit: I think you'll also need to reset all the .ui-state-default elements on each `onSelect` so that if a user first picks "24" and it turns blue, but then picks "17" I believe it will still be blue, so:

```
$(function(){
    $('#cal').datepicker({
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            console.log(dateText);
            $('.ui-state-default').css('background-color','transparent');
            $('.ui-state-default:contains(24)').css('background-color','blue');
            // dont do anything else
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hey thanks, though I'm looking for a way to make the calendar not reset at all. My implementation is much more complicated than this example, and repopulating the calendar with all the changes on every click would be much too complex